# Accessing Web Service from other computers

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012

I'm new at the web services. When I started the WebService from Visual Studio the url is :  `htpp://localhost:portnumber/`

I want to access the web service from another computer, which is in the same network.
So I created a new website with the property all unassigned and with the physicall address.
I tried to put the  new website url to the `Use Custom Web Server` in the Project Properties.

But now it always falls in the "Waiting Response" Statu.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

1. use `http` instad of `htpp`
2. use the actual hostname or the IP instead of `localhost`